# Update the value of a dictionary inside a dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to update the value of a `Dictionary` key. The `Dictionary` is inside another `Dictionary`

Example:

```
var dict = ["Slide":["Name":"TestSlideName", "FontSize":"12", "BGColor":"Blue"]]
```

What do I need to do update the value of `FontSize`?
I know I can get the value of `Slide` by doing the following:

```
var slideFromDict = dict["Slide"]
```

I just can't figure out how to update the value of the keys in the slide dictionary

Comment: `dict["Slide"]?["FontSize"] = "42"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need,

```
dict["Slide"]?["FontSize"] = "14"

print(dict) //["Slide": ["FontSize": "14", "BGColor": "Blue", "Name": "TestSlideName"]]
```